# What's the difference between eating 2000 Calories at once compared to eating 4 times a day at 500 Calories?

Tags: nutrition, calories

I wonder is there any difference in how many times I eat per day?

Let's say I eat one big meal in the morning at 2000 Cal (at 9am). Is that any different than having 4 meals at 500 Cal throughout the day (at 9am, 1pm, 5pm, 9pm)?

I think I will be hungry by the end of the day if I eat just once in the morning. But I won't be hungry if I eat 4 times a day at smaller portions? How is that possible? It's still 2000 Calories. Did I just cheat science?

Which way is it better to eat? Maybe twice a day at 1000 Cal? (9am and like 4pm?)

Head scratch.

Comment: Why are you reposting? There are other ways to get attention for an unanswered question. Additionally, please adhere to Stack Exchange's [Be Nice policy](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). Obscenities typically violate that.

Comment: I'm reposting because I didn't get a single answer. I dont have karma to start a bounty.

Comment: But you should be able to start a bounty on the old question just fine.  I have only 101 and I can start a bounty.